# Help verifying my transfer function computation for Non-Inverting OpAmp circuit!

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, transfer-function

Attached is the work I have done to compute the transfer function of the circuit I designed..
I would like help verifying my work / correcting it and determine the phase... I haven't taken a circuits course in 2 years so I am embarrassingly rusty..

The goal is to compute the transfer function so I can relate the Input Voltage to the Output Voltage. This will help me understand how each component effects the system! Plus I really need the practice.

Highlighted in green is what I think its the transfer function for the OpAmp output voltage (Vx) with respect to the input voltage (Vin).. But I'm having quite a hard time trying to compute the rest of the circuit so i have a transfer function that relates Vout for Vin.

What I think may be happening is when the diode conducts, Vx = Vout, thus what is in green / yellow is the final answer?
Or does the Diode, smoothing capacitor, and bleed resistor play a roll here as well? (I imagine it does, but this is the hump i cannot get over).[image]

If someone could please assist me in verifying this work, or providing me with the correct solution so i can correct it. That would be very much appreciate!!

Comment: The diode is a nonlinear element, it' can't be considered in a Laplace operation. What you have there is a highpass (due to `C1`), so the output will be alternating, and `D1` will only conduct for the positive halfs of the cycles. Only then `R4` and `C2` will act as a lowpass filter. In short, you can't use Laplace with `D1` *unless* you have a small signal analysis, which implies the possibility of linearizing the diode's transfer function around one very small point where the variations of the signal can be considered linear.